# Не понимаю где нужная мне панель в окне. UE4

Tags: unreal-engine-4, unreal-engine

Тут проще объяснить в скринах. Захожу в блупринт с анимацией, ожидая увидеть вот это:
[image: описание]

Если быть точнее, то панель снизу Notifies.
Однако, вижу вот это:

[image: описание]

Никак не могу понять что именно мне нужно открыть, куда тыкнуть, чтобы это появилось.
Если кто сталкивался, подскажите. Я двигаюсь по уроку на ютубе и делаю действие в действие, но окно выглядит иначе.

Comment: так она ж у тебя просто сблоку

Comment: Да, там с боку есть, но там ничего нельзя сделать. Две функции : добавить, удалить. А мне нужно именно видеть их на таймплайне, передвигать и тд

Comment: Добрый день!  для того что бы было такое окно, необходимо записать анимацию после этого сохранить её и открыть в новом окне. Тогда будет данное окно.